# Column selection using checkbox in Angular

Tags: angular, checkbox

I have a requirement in my current project to get the values of the selected column by checking the checkbox. Normally we will add  the checkbox in row and we will get the values. Can anyone guide me , is this possible and if so can you please suggest how to do that?

Thanks,
Sara

Comment: Please share some code, what you've tried, and where you're getting stuck.

Answer (score 0):

suppose below is your table where you displaying your data

```
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let item of employee">
    <td><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isChecked" (change)="getValue(item)" /></<td>
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.surname}}</td>
    <td>{{item.code}}</td>

</tr><tbody>
```

and below is your method on component

```
   getValue(event: any){
     // you will get the row value here when you check your checkBox
   console.log(event);
}
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by attaching a checkbox at table header and bind it with a function that will display the value based on selected columns. Now when you select a checkbox you have to send a unique value which will be used to identify which column is selected. Then correspondingly you will display that columns value. For more clarification please check the attached demo.

working demo added here: [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-zorro-antd-start-ypcupj)

**NOTE:** see output in console.